# A variable used in its own definition?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation, delayed-execution

An infinite stream:

`val ones: Stream[Int] = Stream.cons(1, ones)`

How is it possible for a value to be used in its own declaration? It seems this should produce a compiler error, yet it works.

Comment: The same way recursive functions work. Think `ones` is a zero-arguments function.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not always a recursive definition. This actually works and produces 1:

```
val a : Int = a + 1
println(a)
```

variable `a` is created when you type `val a: Int`, so you can use it in the definition. `Int` is initialized to 0 by default. A class will be null.

As @Chris pointed out, Stream accepts `=> Stream[A]` so a bit another rules are applied, but I wanted to explain general case. The idea is still the same, but the variable is passed by-name, so this makes the computation recursive. Given that it is passed by name, it is executed lazily. Stream computes each element one-by-one, so it calls `ones` each time it needs next element, resulting in the same element being produces once again. This works:

```
val ones: Stream[Int] = Stream.cons(1, ones)
println((ones take 10).toList) // List(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
```

Though you can make infinite stream easier: `Stream.continually(1)` *Update As @SethTisue pointed out in the comments `Stream.continually` and `Stream.cons` are two completely different approaches, with very different results, because `cons` takes `A` when `continually` takes `=>A`, which means that `continually` recomputes each time the element and stores it in the memory, when `cons` can avoid storing it n times unless you convert it to the other structure like `List`. You should use `continually` only if you need to generate different values. See @SethTisue comment for details and examples.*

But notice that you are required to specify the type, the same as with recursive functions.

And you can make the first example recursive:

```
lazy val b: Int = b + 1
println(b)
```

This will stackoverflow.

Comment: Just a note, `Stream.cons(1, ones)` is a circular structure that uses finite memory, `Stream.continually(1)` is a linear structure that uses potentially unbounded memory.

Comment: @SethTisue Could you explain? Is there any practical difference? Not sure what do you mean. If you do `Stream.continually(1).take(10000000)` it still won't allocate all those numbers

Comment: There is an enormous practical difference between something that uses only a few words of memory, and something that could consume the entire heap. (Note, however, that once you call `take` you end up with the same structure either way, so whether it matters depends on what you actually do with the stream.) Further reading: https://gist.github.com/SethTisue/ce598578874accba98c0, https://groups.google.com/d/msg/scala-user/3yypUKJBP04/Q_bowgIry44J

Comment: @SethTisue wow! I didn't realize that `cons` takes `A`, when `continually` takes `=>A`. I agree this makes these two methods completely different.

Answer (score 9):

Look at the signature of [Stream.cons.apply](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream$$cons$):

> `apply[A](hd: A, tl: ⇒ Stream[A]): Cons[A]`

The `⇒` on the second parameter indicates that it has call-by-name semantics. Therefore your expression `Stream.cons(1, ones)` is not strictly evaluated; the argument `ones` does not need to be computed prior to being passed as an argument for `tl`.

Answer (score 3):

The reason this does not produce a compiler error is because both `Stream.cons` and `Cons` are [non-strict](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_function) and [lazily evaluate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) their second parameter.

`ones` can be used in it's own definition because the object cons has an apply method defined like this:

```
/** A stream consisting of a given first element and remaining elements
 *  @param hd   The first element of the result stream
 *  @param tl   The remaining elements of the result stream
 */
def apply[A](hd: A, tl: => Stream[A]) = new Cons(hd, tl)
```

And Cons is defined like this:

```
final class Cons[+A](hd: A, tl: => Stream[A]) extends Stream[A]
```

Notice that it's second parameter `tl` is passed by name (`=> Stream[A]`) rather than by value. In other words, the parameter `tl` is not evaluated until it is used in the function.

One advantage to using this technique is that **you can compose complex expressions that may be only partially evaluated**.