# Self referencing a val during definition in scala

Tags: scala, recursion, functional-programming, akka

This is something that I found out in scala and it works and I can't figure out why, can anyone explain why this works?

Essentially I can use the reference to a val while I am still defining it (because my other objects/actors take it in as a parameter)

```
val backbone: ActorRef = context.actorOf(
  F_BackBone.props(
    context.actorOf(F_PictureHandler.props(backbone)), 
    context.actorOf(F_UserHandler.props(backbone)), 
    context.actorOf(F_PageProfileHandler.props(backbone))
  )
)
```

I will get a compiler error if I don't explicitly define the type, which makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that in this specific case, although the code compiles, it will not behave correctly since, as suggested in comments on the other answer, the value of `backbone` passed into the other actors is 'null'.

This example demonstrates this:

```
import akka.actor.{Props, Actor, ActorRef, ActorSystem}

class SenderReceiver(sendTo:ActorRef) extends Actor{

  override def preStart(): Unit = {
    self ! "Start"
  }

  def receive = {
    case "Start" => sendTo ! "Hello"
    case "Hello" => println("Received Hello")
  }
}

object SenderReceiver {
  def props(sendTo:ActorRef):Props = Props(new SenderReceiver(sendTo))
}

object Example extends App {

  val system = ActorSystem()

  val actor: ActorRef = system.actorOf(SenderReceiver.props(actor))
  system.awaitTermination()
}
```

This yields the following (repeatedly, since the supervisor strategy tries to restart the actor):

```
[info] [ERROR] [12/01/2015 09:47:04.543] [default-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-9] [akka://default/user/$a] null
[info] java.lang.NullPointerException
[info]  at SenderReceiver$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(example.scala:10)
[info]  at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:467)
[info]  at SenderReceiver.aroundReceive(example.scala:3)
[info]  at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
[info]  at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
[info]  at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
[info]  at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
[info]  at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
[info]  at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
[info]  at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
[info]  at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
[info]  at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

Answer (score 1):

In functional programming languages recursive definitions are an important concept. Think for instance of the classic example of defining the factorial.

For the specific case of Scala, a very nice explanation was given in a post earlier this month:
[A variable used in its own definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33536341/a-variable-used-in-its-own-definition)

Comment: But this isn't a recursive definition, it's a reference getting passed before it's constructed

Comment: Nevertheless, I would say that the comment made in the other thread by Archeg applies: "[...] variable `a` is created when you type `val a: Int`, [...]". You have a user-defined type and not Int, so `backbone` would be initialized to `null` in the right-hand side

Comment: @ChristianHirsch I have same understanding. Which means,  `context.actorOf(F_UserHandler.props(backbone))` will receive `backbone` as `null`, unless it is being evaluated lazily ( call-by-name, lazy val etc ). Perhaps a potential bug is being introduced here via `null`.